# Is there any guidance in Hindu scriptures which describe how to know what is presently in the collective subconsciousness of the human community?

Tags: philosophy, consciousness

I am not talking about reading news to know the current consciousness/awareness, but about the collective subsconscious mind of our planet, is it possible to tap into and find out what are the matters the collective human or planet-wide subconsciousness presently has imprinted in it.

By Hindu scriptures, I mean vedic, vedantic, ithihasic or puranic scriptures or in vedangic (Patanjali's yoga sutras or VyAsa's brahma sutras or in Yoga vAshishta or Kapila's sAnkhya treatise etc.)

Comment: Sex, drugs, meat, liquor, and gold (money). What else? This is all mentioned as the main qualities of kali yuga.

Comment: As side effects of the above the world in it's subconscious thoughts seeks Peace of Mind , pure happiness or joy which is overshadowed by material cravings.